# Add specific action button icon for custom order status to Woocommerce admin orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, icons, orders

I've added several new statuses and they all work fine, but I do not know how to add them as buttons to/in the preview (the "eye").

Can't find a hook for it either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in the following code, I add first a button to admin orders list based on a custom status:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button_example', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button_example( $actions, $order ) {
    // Your custom status (without "wc-")
    $action_slug = 'custom';

    // Set the action button
    $actions[$action_slug] = array(
        'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status='.$action_slug.'&order_id=' . $order->get_id() ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
        'name'      => __( 'Custom', 'woocommerce' ),
        'action'    => $action_slug,
    );

    return $actions;
}
```

Then now this following code I assign an icon "the eye" to the order button:

```
// Set Here the WooCommerce icon for your action button
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_order_actions_button_css' );
function add_custom_order_actions_button_css() {
    // The key slug defined for your action button
    $action_slug = "custom";

    echo '<style>.wc-action-button-'.$action_slug.'::after { font-family: woocommerce !important; content: "\e010" !important; }</style>';
}
```

> Icon comes from included [Woocommerce Icon library](https://rawgit.com/woothemes/woocommerce-icons/master/demo.html)

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

> Or you can use the included [WordPress dashicons icon library](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#align-right)

With this CSS rules instead: `font-family: dashicons !important; content: "\f177" !important;`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much LoicTheAztec! Do you by any chance know which hook I can use if I want to add custom content to the "eye" Preview (to the right after Jack Nicholson)?

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec,
No, what I'm looking for is adding buttons next to "Processing" and "Completed". The buttons available at the bottom when viewing the order via "the eye" = order preview.

Your answer is very helpful for adding custom buttons in the action area, thank you for that.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did something wrong, but if you're referring to this question and the question that followed, I did ask about adding custom content to "pop-up" (lightbox) that shows when clicking the eye.

"I've added several new statuses and they all work fine, but I do not know how to add them as buttons to/in the preview (the "eye")."

Again, if I did something wrong, I'm sorry.

Comment: I want to trigger this wp_remote_post API call when the button is pressed, How can i bind this action into action?

Comment: @NaFi I have answered [your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514069/3730754)… Please, some feed back on it is appreciated.

Comment: @loictheaztecit seems u have deleted the answer

Comment: @NaFi I have republish it… So you can leave a feed back on it.